# vsts customise build summary by adding a chart with azure blob as data source

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-build-task

I need to customise vsts build summary by adding a chart(a pie chart and a bar chart) for which the data source will be azure blob or a local csv file generated after the build execution.

Do we have any default vsts tasks available or 
writing vsts extensions is the only way out of this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is not any built-in official task or extension could achieve your needs. You could go through [Visual Studio Team Services  Marketplace](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/vsts) if there are some 3rd-party extension meet your requirement.

You want to build an extension for VSTS and Microsoft has created a GitHub repo with a number of samples and reading material to get you started. Otherwise, you may have to write your own extension, some tutorials for your reference:

- [VSTS Extensions Samples](https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-extension-samples)
- [Develop Extensions for VSTS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/extend/)

As for how to accessing Azure Storage from a VSTS extension, take a look at this [blog](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudioalmrangers/2017/02/14/accessing-azure-storage-from-a-vsts-extension/).